# updating mutable list in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Im new to multiThreading. I have a list which is referenced by all thread. On certain condition, i want the list to be updated with values from database. The update could happen in any of those thread. How to make certain that when the list is updated, all thread which is looping through all item in list will receive an update to the list they reading through?

Comment: Make sure you synchronize the regions of code where you read/write the list.  If you want a better answer, please post more details and code.

Comment: @sstan thanks.actually im not sure whether i should use volatile or synchronize.ill make the method synchronize. For list, should i use `volatile` for the list?

Comment: No, don't use `volatile` for a list.  In fact, I recommend you never use `volatile` unless you truly understand what it means and does. Actually, I guess I could say the same thing about multi-threading in general.  Multi-threading is deceivingly hard to get right.  Please take the time to read/learn/absorb how it works before using it in serious code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common situations in concurrent programming occurs when more than one
execution thread shares a resource. In a concurrent application, it is normal that multiple
threads read or write the same data or have access to the same file or database connection.
These shared resources can provoke error situations or data inconsistency and we have to
implement mechanisms to avoid these errors.
The solution for these problems comes with the concept of critical section. A critical section
is a block of code that accesses a shared resource and can't be executed by more than one
thread at the same time.
**To implement critical sections, Java (and almost all programming
languages) offers synchronization mechanisms**

synchronization mechanisms offered by the Java language:

The keyword synchronized

The Lock interface and its implementations

Make the method synchronized where you are writing to the list,so that only one thread can update the list.

```
synchronized void updateList(){
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: how is the performance of synchronized? will code become slower as each thread need to take turn using the critical section?

Comment: yes,only single thread can access...to fine grain the synchronization look for synchronization blocks where you can synchronize the necessary lines of code instead of whole method.

Comment: very Interesting @KDP. ill use synchronization blocks where it will wrap around only updating part whereas retrieving resultset from database is set loose. thank you.

Comment: @sstan does that means each thread not only need to take turn updating the list, but they also need to take turn reading the list after update take place?

Comment: ReadWriteLock will allow multiple readers or a single writer to hit the list at the same time.  This will be more performant for many scenarios than the exclusive locking provided by synchronized.  More performance can be had with more clever locking strategies (e.g. having 20 locks for a single list - each covering some range of elements, or hierarchical lock structures). Concurrent collections is a fascinating subject - well worth spending some google time on.